# WPF RichTextBox-Foreground color from current caret position when selection is empty

Tags: wpf, selection, richtextbox, foreground, is-empty

I have RichTextBox and Button,when a text is selected in RichTextBox method Button_Click changes the text foreground color, but when selected text is empty, foreground color doesn't change when I add  a new text in RichTextBox. The foreground color is still the same.

**View**

```
<StackPanel Margin="10">
        <Button Height="50" Content="Set Color" Click="Button_Click"/>
        <RichTextBox x:Name="richTextBox" Height="198" />
</StackPanel>
```

**Code-Behind**

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

        if (!richTextBox.Selection.IsEmpty)
        {
            //selection isn't empty foreground changed
            richTextBox.Selection.ApplyPropertyValue(RichTextBox.ForegroundProperty, RandomColor());
        }
        else
        {
            //here code when selection text in richtextbox is empty????
        }
        richTextBox.Focus();
 }

private Brush RandomColor()
{
        Brush[] brushes = new Brush[]{
            Brushes.Red,Brushes.Pink,Brushes.Blue,Brushes.Green,Brushes.Yellow
        };
        Random rnd = new Random();
        return brushes[rnd.Next(brushes.Length)];

 }
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: How to set foreground color, when i write a new text.

Comment: You want to be able to change the foreground colour, so that when the user continues typing it starts in a new colour?

Comment: Yes, when the user clicks button and continues typing foreground color is still the same as previous color of text. I want new color.

Answer (score 1):

You need to start a new `Run` within the `FlowDocument`:

```
private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var newRun = new Run(string.Empty, MyRichTextBox.CaretPosition.GetInsertionPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward)) { Foreground = Brushes.Red };
    MyRichTextBox.CaretPosition.Paragraph.Inlines.Add(newRun);
    MyRichTextBox.CaretPosition = newRun.ContentEnd;
    MyRichTextBox.Focus();
}
```

Comment: Thank, but your code works only when richtextbox is empty or I add new line.  i want change color in any time. Vor example as it is in Microsoft Word.

Comment: It works for me without creating a new line. I type some text in black, I click the button, I continue typing in red.

Comment: I am using .NET 4.5.
I think the problem is that after clicking the button, you click the mouse back into the RichTextBox and you are entering the old run. Click your button and then use Tab key to return to the RichTextBox and resume typing.

Comment: When I clicked button, after back at the end of the text in RichTextBox, resume typing color is black. When I made spaces, after clicked Button and retrun to the RichTextBox and resume typing color is red.

Comment: I have tested in Microsoft Word 2013 and it works the same way. Type in black, change font colour to blue, click on document, continue typing and it types in black.

Comment: Thank you very much, but Now i have another problem. When the foreground color change, all formats text for example bold or italic, which were set earlier, are disabled. I want to have RichTextBox which is working similar as Microsoft Office Word.

Comment: Ok, you're just gradually expanding the question... Copy the formatting properties of the previous inline and modify it.

Comment: Is there any other way without richTextBox.Focus() at the end? I use ColorPicker from Extended WPF Toolkit Community Edition  to change Foreground Color,I can't set rich focus in the event SelectedColorChanged. Any ideas?

Comment: I think the best solution would be to find a way to set the focus

Comment: Sorry, I can't resolve my problem. I think, that this is not the fault focus of RichTextBox. I have in RichTextBox some text for example green. I change in ColorPicker selected color to Red. Actual selected color is Red. Next, I set caret in RichTextBox at the end of the Flowdocument,
I continue typing in green. Why??? I want to continue typing in acutal color of ColorPicker(In this case RED)

Comment: Instead of using the mouse to re-enter the RichTextBox after choosing colour, you must call the Focus method.

Comment: @GlenThomas You are now my best friend ! One day on StackOverflow and all "complicated" solutions with override and customized richtextbox... Simple, clean and work perfectly !! Thanks so much :)